# Handling the back button while using multi step remote links

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a 3 step report which loads by clicking a link with the `remote: :true` option, so it reloads a part of the page instead of refreshing the whole page. I also provide the user with breadcrumbs, so he/she can easily navigate between the steps. However, most users use the browser back button, which of course reloads the whole page. What is the "Rails way" of dealing with this? If the browser back button is clicked the user should see the previous step in the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to control the history the user sees, but aren't doing full page reloads on form submit, you should be manipulating the history state via Javascript's [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) and friends.

Assuming the responds to the submitted form is some sort of evaluated Javascript, simply include the history state manipulations there.